# Manage Size and Colour of CheckBox in Latex

Tags: formatting, box, forms

I want to be able to place parameters on the size of the box and be able to choose colour of the `checkbox function. Here is my Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Comments of the Departmental Rep:} \hfil Approved/Not Approved
        
        Approved \CheckBox[name = check1]{ }  \hfil  Not Approved \CheckBox[name = check2]{ }
        
        \item \textbf{Comments of the Faculty Rep:} \hfil Approved/Not Approved
        
        Approved \CheckBox[name = check1]{ }  \hfil  Not Approved \CheckBox[name = check2]{ }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is the [image: output of my trial]

**What I Want**

I want the boxs to be smaller and the colour of its borders to be black.

Comment: If possible, can you post a reference image for your box design?

Comment: I have updated my question on your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this one you expected?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\custombox}[1][\relax]{\bgroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}\fbox{}\egroup}


    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Comments of the Departmental Rep:} \hfil Approved/Not Approved
        
        Approved \custombox[name = check1]{ }  \hfil  Not Approved \custombox[name = check2]{ }
        
        \item \textbf{Comments of the Faculty Rep:} \hfil Approved/Not Approved
        
        Approved \custombox[name = check1]{ }  \hfil  Not Approved \custombox[name = check2]{ }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]